# GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9

Tags: android, google-plus, google-authentication

I'm trying to run the GooglePlayServices samples but on the Auth sample I get the following error when pressing the Greet Me button:

com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9

and Signature not valid. Found XXXX

the error is on the call 
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);

I didn't do anything else, just compile and run the sample.

I do have the Google Play Services installed on my device.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The rollout of Google Play services only applies to Android 2.2+ devices running the latest version of the Google Play store.
You will get the [error code 9](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SERVICE_INVALID) when the version of the Google Play services installed on this device is not authentic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add this to `build.gradle` it work with me

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

or you need to update your emulator to android 11.0 (R)
that it solve me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29773324)

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my case is that the emulator did not have the Play Store installed, so I installed another emulator that if I had that app and voila, it was solved.

Comment: The answer is better suited as a comment.